# Jmeter master slave connection time out error

Tags: performance, jmeter, load-testing, distribution, connection-timeout

we are facing issue, while trying to run jmeter distribution testing with master and slave configuration on different machines. Jmeter distribution test is running fine on same machine , but we are getting Connection refused to host: xxx.xxx.xxx.xx; nested exception is:java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect Failed to configure xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx

Answer (score 0):

Most probably your networking configuration is not correct. Make sure that:

1. JMeter master and slaves reside in the same [subnet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subnetwork), to wit you should be able to reach out from any machine to any machine
2. The network [ports](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_(computer_networking)) are open in the [firewalls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firewall_(computing)) so JMeter master could communicate with slaves, the ports are:

   - `1099`
   - the port you define as `server.rmi.localport`
   - the ports you define as `client.rmi.localport`

Check out the following materials:

- [Remote hosts and RMI configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#remote)
- [Apache JMeter Distributed Testing Step-by-step](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_distributed_testing_step_by_step.html)
- [How to Perform Distributed Testing in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-perform-distributed-testing-in-jmeter)

In case of any problems look into [*jmeter.log* file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/hints_and_tips.html#debug_logging), normally it contains enough information in order to get to the bottom of the issue